# How to pass variable in MongoDB query?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoDB update function that performs differently according to the key submitted. If I do if-else like below, it works fine:

```
if(req.body.nature == 'In') { 
const user = await db.findOne({ id: 'idNum' });
    user.dailyTime.push({
      in: true
    });
    await user.save();
}

if(req.body.nature == 'out') { 
const user = await db.findOne({ id: 'idNum' });
    user.dailyTime.push({
      out: true
    });
    await user.save();
}
```

However, as code becomes longer, it becomes error-prone. I have tried to do below:

```
if(req.body.nature == 'In') { data = {in: true}}
if(req.body.nature == 'Out') { data = {out: true}}

const user = await db.findOne({ id: 'idNum' });
    user.dailyTime.push({
      data
    });
    await user.save();
```

This did not work.

Answer (score 1):

type of `data` is object

so replace

```
 user.dailyTime.push({
      data
    });
```

with

```
    user.dailyTime.push(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the curly bracket `{}` on the push method.

```
if(req.body.nature == 'In') { data = {in: true}}
if(req.body.nature == 'Out') { data = {out: true}}

const user = await db.findOne({ id: 'idNum' });
    user.dailyTime.push(data);
    await user.save();
```